# Inserting Dataframe into Outlook email message

Tags: html, pandas, dataframe, outlook

I'm trying to insert a dataframe into an email and tried using pretty html tables and to_html. The email displays and everything looks great except the table is not embedded. I've tried several methods but nothing seems to work. Any thoughts? Code below. (And thanks in advance!)

```
    import win32com.client as client
    from pretty_html_table import build_table
    outlook = client.Dispatch('Outlook.Application')
    message = outlook.CreateItem(0)
    message.Display()
    message.To = "EMAIL"
    message.Subject = "Action Required - XXXX"
    html_body = """

    HTML CODE HERE

    """.format(build_table(df_final, 'blue_light'))

    message.HTMLBody = html_body
```

Comment: `str.format` requires a place to put it in, usually `{}`; your code uses `HTML CODE HERE`, which is not valid. Just replace `HTML CODE HERE` with `{}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I was able to embed a pretty table into an e-mail

```
table_checked = build_table(<Your DF>, 'blue_dark', width = 'auto')

body = f"""
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
    <p>Team,<br />
    <br />
    Blah Blah Blah</b>.
    {table_checked}
    blah blah blah<br />
    <br />
    Respecfully,<br />
    <Your Name> <br />
    <br />
    <b>end of the email</b></p>
</body>

</html>
"""
```

Comment: this seems to work! I'll need to edit the table a bit to make it look cleaner but this is great. Thank you!

Comment: Awesome! Yea you might need to do some editing as this is just a template you can use for your own work. If the answer worked for you please hit the upvote and check it as answer so others will be able to find it who have similar questions.

Comment: won't let me upvote - don't have the rep. But I tagged as answer. One other question! Does the pretty table strip hyperlinks? I have this in the last column of my dataframe but it shows literally, not converting to a hyperlink in the email. .apply(lambda x: f'<a href="my link"={x}>{x}</a>')